# What does botframework "Login failed due to MSA collision" mean? And how to fix?

Tags: bots, botframework

Today Microsoft announced their botframework during the Build2016 presentation.  I would like to register a bot via https://dev.botframework.com/ but when attempting to log in using my existing Microsoft credentials I receive the following error "Login failed due to MSA collision."  What does this error mean?  And how can I get logged into Microsoft's botframework.com so that I can register a bot?

## botframework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you have a first and last name set on your MSA account.  This may be causing the issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me

Comment: Where can you change info on your MSA account?  My technet account shows my name, but I don't know if that's the right page/place to change it.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. It can be changed at https://profile.live.com/ - if its already set like it was for me, press edit, and press save.. that solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can change it at https://profile.live.com; it says Edit in the top left corner.

Comment: Even after changing my first name and last name, I still get the same error. Please help. I had bots on the site, now I can't access them because of this error. 

https://dev.botframework.com/api/Account is returning 401 error