# dev.botframework.com login fails

Tags: botframework

Not a programming question, but maybe someone from the community can help...

I'm having trouble logging in to dev.botframework.com
After clicking on the "Sign in" link, selecting my Microsoft Azure user name, and providing the Microsoft account password, I'm getting this answer:

We are unable to login with '...'. Please logout and try login with a different account

The only somewhat related issue I found was this:

[What does botframework “Login failed due to MSA collision” mean? And how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319675/what-does-botframework-login-failed-due-to-msa-collision-mean-and-how-to-fix)

However, none of this seemed to apply.

Comment: Try logging in a private/incognito session of your browser. The login is working just fine; just tried it.

Comment: That worked! I just opened a new private Window in my browser (Firefox), and the login succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from [Ezequiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90081/ezequiel-jadib) solved it:
I had to login through a private window, then it worked.
I suspect it was an issue with cookies - since then, I was also able to login through a normal window in Firefox.